# get category of a Unicode letter

Tags: c#, unicode, char

As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w.aspx):

`Char.IsLetter() determines whether a Char is a member of any category of Unicode letter.`

is it possible the get the **category of Unicode letter** itself, when `Char.IsLetter()` is `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - I think you want [`CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(char)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6sx68ke.aspx) or [`Char.GetUnicodeCategory(char)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz49h034.aspx).

See the documentation for the differences - the suggestion is that you use `CharUnicodeInfo`, in order to get the value in the *current* Unicode standard.